# how to keep running C# application after windows log off

Tags: c#, windows, rest, service

I wrote a C# application using RESTful web services. This application should interact periodically with our server application. I want this program to keep running in the background even if the user logs out of the computer. How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Perhaps you need to write a windows service.

Comment: using Windows Service project.

Comment: If it's web service, deploy it to IIS.

Comment: For scenarios like these, I usually write a C# Console application (i.e. _not_ a Service) and use the built-in Windows Task Scheduler to start it under a dedicated user account (e.g. "MySchedulerUser"), e.g. upon system start or, for periodical tasks, to run every _n_ minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your application to stop when the user logs out, then the application can't be running in the user's session (really a [WinStation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx)).  That implies your app needs to run in a different session.  The sessions that don't logout are service sessions.  Run Task Manager and add the Session ID column, and view all processes, and you'll see what I mean.

So your application needs to run as, or be launched by, a service.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer don't keep the service running under the specific user account. If you do so then also it won't work if you logged off.